# Returning lvalue reference to modified rvalue argument

Tags: c++, templates, reference, rvalue-reference

Is the following valid C++ code? Also why could it possibly be a bad practice? And what is your suggestion for refactoring taking into account that T can be a heavy type?

```
template<class T>
T& increment(T&& val)
{
    ++val;
    return val;
}

template<class T>
T incremented(T const& val)
{
    return val + 1;
}

int get_int()
{
    return 333;
}

int main()
{   
    auto i0{ get_int() };
    auto const i1{ get_int() };

    increment(i0);
    auto _i1 = incremented(i1);
    auto _i2 = increment(get_int());

    return _i2;
}
```

Comment: _And what is your suggestion for refactoring taking into account that T can be a heavy type?_ I would always prefer prefix over postfix inc./dec. The latter comes usually with a copy, the former usually not. (In general, I use postfix only if I have a good reason for this.)

Comment: Looks like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the better site for your question...

Comment: This is a very poor choice of function name for `increment`. Judging by the name of the function nobody expects the parameter to go unmodified and a new object being returned instead. It's hard to tell that `increment(i1);` basically doesn't have any effect; it would be better if this would not compile at all to indicate this to the user and instead rename the function to `T incremented(T const& val)`. As for optimizing this on "heavy objects" I'd recommend relying on `T::T(const T&&)`, preincrement and copy ellison to avoid allocation of new resources, at least if `T` supports it.